# Reply to sender profile is failing

Tags: marketing-cloud

We have create a sender profile abc@xyz.com.au. We send email from marketing cloud and the mail comes with From address as abc@xyz.com.au, but when we do reply to the mail we are getting a delivery failure.

"Your message wasn't delivered because the recipient's e-mail provider rejected it."

Is there any pointers to it

Thanks and Regards,
Anumol Antony

Comment: There are a couple of reasons why this might be happening. Is xyz.com the domain you find after the @ in your own company email address (eg anumol@xyz.com)? If not, is xyz.com exclusively used for the Marketing Cloud? If yes to the last one, have you configured Reply Mail Management in Marketing Cloud?

Comment: Hi Stephan, The from Address abc@xyz.com.au, the @xyz.com.au is the reply sub domain created for our organisation, we have configured the reply mail management in our syste,

Comment: If you haven't already, I would make sure to put in a SFMC global support case on it. This sounds like an issue with RMM or domain config.  I know there have been times when international email addresses have caused issue in SFMC, but mostly this has been around sending.